# Responsive Design - sidebar looks different on mobile device using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

the left sidebar on my site: http://traumbad-muenchen.de/unternehmensnews/ looks ok so far.

If I open the same site on iphone the sidebars background color and the text color looks different.

I already looked in the responsive.css to change the settings but I can`t find a way to change the background color and the text color.

Could anybody help?

thx
Heidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In responsive.css at row 259

(http://traumbad-muenchen.de/wp-content/themes/hueman/responsive.css)

Change the background-color of your sidebar as you want :)